# Diferencia entre exec() y exec_()

Tags: python, exec

En Python cual diferencia entre exec() y exec_()?

tienen alguna relación o no tiene que ver una con la otra?

Gracias.

Comment: Añade algo de contexto a tu pregunta. En python estándar no hay nada que sea `exec()` ni `exec_()`. Seguramente se trate de algún GUI que estás usando. Sé más específico.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder.
Estaba viendo que en python exec() es una función y y en PyQt es un método pero con el guion bajo, exec_(). quería saber si la nomenclatura del guion bajo después del nombre significa algo o solo es parte del nombre. como por ejemplo cuando encapsulamos un método, usamos 2 guiones bajos a la izquierda. __metodo()

Comment: OK. Entiendo que preguntas si tiene algo de especial la nomenclatura, y no si existe alguna diferencia de funcionamiento. Te lo explico como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tiene un conjunto de [palabras reservadas](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) que no se pueden emplear para nombrar variables o funciones como son `if`, `return` o `def`, por ejemplo. Además de  estas palabras, se recomienda no usar los nombres de las [funciones predefinidas](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) (*built-in functions*) como `max`, `int`, `iter` o  **`exec`**. No está prohibido, pero si usas el nombre para tu variable la función predefinida queda inaccesible. A la hora de pasar chequeadores de código (*linters*) te advertirán de este problema y pedirán que lo cambies.

En realidad no es del todo cierto que las funciones predefinidas queden inaccesibles. Todas pertenecen al módulo `builtins`, con lo que siempre puedes acceder a ellas calificando el nombre con el nombre del módulo. Por ejemplo, `builtins.exec` para acceder a la función `exec`. Pero es mejor no usar este módulo en nuestro código, podría tener problemas en alguna implementación del intérprete python que optimize estas funciones.

Por otro lado, puedes aislar efectos indeseados manteniendo separados los *espacios de nombres* (*namespaces*). Nunca hacer un `import * from module`, ya que se pueden enmascarar las funciones predefinidas por las del módulo. Es mejor hacer un `import module` y calificar cada una de las funciones como `module.function()`.

Por convenio, para evitar problemas con las palabras reservadas y funciones predefinidas, se suele añadir un `'_'` al final del nombre de las funciones. Lo verás bastante como nombre de argumento para pasar una clase, que se nombra como `class_`, aunque hay quien prefiere usar `cls` o `klass`, según gustos. Lo mismo para el caso que nos ocupa, que nombra al método `exec_` para que no haya problemas con la función predefinida `exec`. Es un convenio, sin ninguna motivación más que evitar un posible conflicto con otras funciones con el mismo nombre.